# Перенаправление с поддомена на папку без переконфигурации Апача

Tags: apache, linux

Есть сервер, на котором работает Апач. Для нового пользователя создается своя папка. Возможно ли настроить Апач так, что он будет перекидывать с соответствующего поддомена на папку пользователя, причем никаких изменений в установках Апача не потребуется? Например, с

```
address.user.server.ru
```

будет перекидывать на

```
/home/user/address/www
```

Comment: Боюсь, что не получится. Нужно править конфиги.

Comment: Есть целая инструкции как это делать, причем не одна: [Apache: Автоматические субдомены](http://server-tuning.info/apache/auto-subdomains.html).Остальные можно найти по "Apache: Автоматические субдомены" в яндексе/гугле.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то для этих целей пойдет [`mod_vhost_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).

> Этот модуль создает динамически формируемые виртуальные хосты, допуская IP-адреса и/или Host'ы: заголовок HTTP-запроса будет использоваться как часть пути, чтобы определить, какие файлы надо обслужить.